# Parse nested HTML that's within a string in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsing

I'm building a type ahead feature in React.

I have wrapper component that has an array of objects, and it renders `item`; which's a stateless component.

So, suppose I have `const name= 'Hasan'`. Which gets parsed to >> `const parsedName = Ha<span>san</span>`; assuming the term to search for is `san`.

I have tried `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: parsedName }}` attribute on the parent element, but it didn't work.

> With plain html this would be: `el.innerHTML = parsedName`

**The goal is to style the span as desired.** Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const name = 'san';
    const parsedName = name.replace(new RegExp('san', 'ig'), '<span>span</span>');
    return (
     <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: parsedName}}/>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Without code its hard to tell what's wrong. I have created a working snippet here that might help you debug your issue.

Updated the example based on the comment.

Comment: That's correct and simple if I were to make it just a string. However, the problem arises when I populate the parsed name as a JSX element. (e.g. `name = name.replace(new RegExp('san', 'ig'), <span className="matched">san</span>);`
Then it renders it as an object and can't parse it to html.

Comment: Hi Hasan. I have updated the example. Let me know if I have still misunderstood the problem..